# Groupby on two column and applying transform(Partition), rolling and concatenation on particular column using pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, string-concatenation

I have DataFrame with columns(period, spn, cpt, payer). I have to concatenate column(payer)values for only 2-period(rolling for only two months). Sample of DF:

```
period     spn  cpt payer
7/1/2018    a   23  UNITED, HEALTH
7/1/2018    a   24  CARE, MEDI
7/1/2018    b   23  ASSIGN
8/1/2018    a   23  ASSIGN
8/1/2018    a   24  CARE, MEDI
8/1/2018    b   23  ASSIGN, MEDI
9/1/2018    a   23  ASSIGN
9/1/2018    a   24  MEDI
9/1/2018    b   23  ASSIGN, MEDI
```

I have tried with:
`df.groupby(['spn', 'cpt'])['payer'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(2, min_periods = 1).apply(', '.join, raw=False))`

I got an error: **cannot handle this type -> object**.

So converted column(payer) to string-type and tried with same above code. But I got same error. Please help me to solve this issue.

Expected results

```
period    spn   cpt  payer             payer_concate
7/1/2018    a   23   UNITED, HEALTH    UNITED, HEALTH, ASSIGN
7/1/2018    a   24   CARE, MEDI        CARE, MEDI, CARE, MEDI
7/1/2018    b   23   ASSIGN            ASSIGN, ASSIGN, MEDI
8/1/2018    a   23   ASSIGN            ASSIGN, ASSIGN
8/1/2018    a   24   CARE, MEDI        CARE, MEDI, MEDI
8/1/2018    b   23   ASSIGN, MEDI      ASSIGN, MEDI, ASSIGN, MEDI
9/1/2018    a   23   ASSIGN            ASSIGN
9/1/2018    a   24   MEDI              MEDI
9/1/2018    b   23   ASSIGN, MEDI      ASSIGN, MEDI
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: instead of sharing screenshots, can you please share something that we can reproduce? at least share using `print()` so we copy and paste and work on your problem

Comment: Thanks for the look over. And I have replaced images with values(which can copied and work).

Answer (score 3):

First sort the values by period. Then use groupby and transform and concatenate neighboring payers. Because there are no followers to the last period, this values will be `None`, therefore they are filled by `combine_first` with the original values from `df`.

```
s = df.sort_values('period').groupby(['spn','cpt']).payer\
                       .transform(lambda x: x +',' + x.shift(-1)).combine_first(df.payer)
df["payer_concatenate"] = s
```

result

```
    period      spn cpt payer           payer_concatenate
0   7/1/2018    a   23  UNITED,HEALTH   UNITED,HEALTH,ASSIGN
1   7/1/2018    a   24  CARE,MEDI       CARE,MEDI,CARE,MEDI
2   7/1/2018    b   23  ASSIGN          ASSIGN,ASSIGN,MEDI
3   8/1/2018    a   23  ASSIGN          ASSIGN,ASSIGN
4   8/1/2018    a   24  CARE,MEDI       CARE,MEDI,MEDI
5   8/1/2018    b   23  ASSIGN,MEDI     ASSIGN,MEDI,ASSIGN,MEDI
6   9/1/2018    a   23  ASSIGN          ASSIGN
7   9/1/2018    a   24  MEDI            MEDI
8   9/1/2018    b   23  ASSIGN,MEDI     ASSIGN,MEDI
```

Comment: Thank you @pythonic833 @Gunnvant. And I worked to get my answer through this code: ```df.sort_values(by = 'period', ascending = False, inplace = True)``` .
               ```df['payer_concate'] = pd.concat([df.groupby(['spn', 'cpt'])['payer'].shift(i) for i in range(2)], axis=1).fillna('').T.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))``` . which is faster than @pythonic833's code. Thank you guys for your valuable time and code

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data=pd.DataFrame({'period':['7/1/2018','7/1/2018','7/1/2018','8/1/2018','8/1/2018','8/1/2018','9/1/2018','9/1/2018','9/1/2018'],'span':['a','a','b','a','a','b','a','a','b'],'cpt':[23,24,23,23,24,23,23,24,23],'payer':['UNITED, HEALTH','CARE, MEDI','ASSIGN','ASSIGN','CARE, MEDI','ASSIGN, MEDI','ASSIGN','MEDI','ASSIGN, MEDI']})
Groups=[data.groupby(['span','cpt']).groups[a] for a in data.groupby(['span','cpt']).groups]
for grp in Groups:
    data.loc[grp,'payer_1']=(data.iloc[grp]['payer'].shift(-1)).values

def get_cols(row):
    if row['payer_1'] is np.nan:
        return row['payer']
    else:
        return row['payer']+", "+row['payer_1']
data['final']=data.apply(get_cols,axis=1)
```

data

```
         period span  cpt           payer       payer_1                       final
0  7/1/2018    a   23  UNITED, HEALTH        ASSIGN      UNITED, HEALTH, ASSIGN
1  7/1/2018    a   24      CARE, MEDI    CARE, MEDI      CARE, MEDI, CARE, MEDI
2  7/1/2018    b   23          ASSIGN  ASSIGN, MEDI        ASSIGN, ASSIGN, MEDI
3  8/1/2018    a   23          ASSIGN        ASSIGN              ASSIGN, ASSIGN
4  8/1/2018    a   24      CARE, MEDI          MEDI            CARE, MEDI, MEDI
5  8/1/2018    b   23    ASSIGN, MEDI  ASSIGN, MEDI  ASSIGN, MEDI, ASSIGN, MEDI
6  9/1/2018    a   23          ASSIGN           NaN                      ASSIGN
7  9/1/2018    a   24            MEDI           NaN                        MEDI
8  9/1/2018    b   23    ASSIGN, MEDI           NaN                ASSIGN, MEDI
```

Regards Gunnvant, Jigsaw

Comment: Pandas rolling() doesn't support anything other than a handful of numerical aggregation functions such mean(), min() etc. I also tried the rolling followed by an apply() approach but I think you can't pass any arbitrary function in apply() after you have done rolling() operation.

Comment: Yes, shifting is the better option in this case since we only want to have two concatenations. But rolling should work too  `.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x[0] + x[1]) ` might work.

Comment: Ok, I checked that. It seems like rolling can only handle numbers not strings. But the problem can still be solved like you did or there is a way to do it with `groupby`

Comment: Saw your approach, I think yours is more Pandas like

Answer (score 0):

I could answer some part of your question :

```
data['period']=pd.to_datetime(data.period)
data['month']= data.period.dt.month
data.set_index(['spn', 'cpt','period'], inplace=True)
df = data.groupby(['spn', 'cpt']).agg(','.join)
df = data.merge(df, on=['spn','cpt'])
df.rename({'payer_x':'payer','payer_y':'payer_concate'})
```

output:

```
spn cpt           payer  month                     payer_concate

a   23   UNITED, HEALTH      7      UNITED, HEALTH,ASSIGN,ASSIGN
    23           ASSIGN      8      UNITED, HEALTH,ASSIGN,ASSIGN
    23           ASSIGN      9      UNITED, HEALTH,ASSIGN,ASSIGN
    24       CARE, MEDI      7        CARE, MEDI,CARE, MEDI,MEDI
    24       CARE, MEDI      8        CARE, MEDI,CARE, MEDI,MEDI
    24             MEDI      9        CARE, MEDI,CARE, MEDI,MEDI
b   23           ASSIGN      7  ASSIGN,ASSIGN, MEDI,ASSIGN, MEDI
    23     ASSIGN, MEDI      8  ASSIGN,ASSIGN, MEDI,ASSIGN, MEDI
    23     ASSIGN, MEDI      9  ASSIGN,ASSIGN, MEDI,ASSIGN, MEDI
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please check that your results are not matching what I am looking for. After applying groupby, need to roll for two months. But you have taken all the values(for all the months) for aggregations

Comment: Please let me know. If you got time to look into it.

Comment: Hi @RaghavendraS, I could answer the first part of your question. Once I figure out how to do it I will be happy to share that with you